# Javascript: drop-in text readability from a webpage

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

There are quite a few "readability" bookmarklets, browser addons, browser builtins, etc. They all basically "try" to get the "main text" from an arbitrary page.

What are the top javascript libraries for getting the "main text" from a web page?

For the purpose of this OP, the best answer is the one that can correctly extract the main text from the largest variety of pages that you throw at it. But if you know of a "human-assisted" system that runs entirely in javascript (where the user helps the algorithm find the text by for example eliminating some choices), I'd like to know!